# Create Instrument Class (Dealing with arrays and methods)

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

1. The array with the names of strings of the instrument is a required field in the Instrument class, but in order to simplify the program, I will accept solutions in which tuning of an instrument is not done separately on each string. However, if you want to work with each string, a good example is found in the Week 8 Additional Notes, in which another class of instruments represented by Tuba is considered.
2. Please use Listings 8.3 and 8.4 as models to organize your code for Project 3 in two separate classes, one for defining the instrument, and the other one to test instruments.
3. Make the methods in the Instrument class to return String, unlike the example in the requirements, where such methods write directly to standard output. This is necessary because it is required that output of the test class be written to a file specified by the user on the command line.
4. In the test class you must have an array with 10 elements of Instrument type, populate the array with instances of the Instrument class (by using the new operator on the class constructor), and the use a while or for loop to perform tests (i.e. call Intrument class methods) on each array element.
5. As specified in the requirements, the test class must be started with an argument in the command line:

   ```
                       java Mynamep3tst myfilename.txt
   ```

where myfilename.txt is the file where all output must go. This file name should be used in the program as follows (see Listing 14.13):

```
             java.io.File file = new java.io.File(args[0]);

       java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
```

and when you have a message to be sent to the file,

```
                         output.println(message);
```

*My question is every time I try to create a new object of the instrument class within my for loop with the use of the array instrumentContent it causes an error. I cannot understand if I am not allowed to create new objects in this fashion. If I am not allowed to do it this way what is the proper way to do it so that each of my arrays are used?***

```
class StringInstrument {//begin class
//declare variables
boolean isTuned;
boolean isPlaying;
boolean band;
public String nameOfInstrument; 
int numberOfStrings; 
String nameofStringsInInstrument[] = {"E", "A", "D", "G", "B"}; //an array of string names

public StringInstrument() {//begin contructor
    numberOfStrings = 5;    
    isTuned = false;    
    isPlaying = false;
    band = false;
 }//end constructor

public int NumberOfStrings(int stringNumber){//begin method
    System.out.println("The number of strings for the " + nameOfInstrument + " is " + stringNumber );
    return this.numberOfStrings = stringNumber;
}//end method

public String InstrumentNameGet() {//begin method
    return nameOfInstrument;
}//end method

public void SetInstrumentName (String instrumentName) {//begin getter method
        nameOfInstrument = instrumentName;
    }//end method

public String InstrumentNameDisplay() {//begin method
    System.out.println("Your instrument is the " + nameOfInstrument);
    return nameOfInstrument;
}//end method

public boolean PlayInstrument(){//begin method
    System.out.println("You are playing your " + nameOfInstrument);
    return isPlaying = true;
}//end method

public boolean TuneInstrument(){//begin method
    System.out.println("Tune " + nameOfInstrument);
    return isTuned = true;
}//end method

public boolean stopTuneInstrument() {//begin method
    System.out.println("The" + nameOfInstrument + " is out of tune.");
    return isTuned = false;
}//end method 

public boolean StopPlayInstrument() {//begin method
    System.out.println("The " + nameOfInstrument + " has stopped playing");
    return isTuned = false;
}//end method

public boolean PlayInstrumentBand() {//begin method
    System.out.println("The " + nameOfInstrument + " is playing in a band");
    return band = true;
}//end method

public boolean StopPlayInstrumentBand() {//begin method
    System.out.println("The " + nameOfInstrument + " has stoped playing with the band");
    System.out.println("\n");
    return band = false;
}//end method
```

}//end class

public class RandyGilmanP3 {//begin class

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{//begin main  

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("RandyGilmanP3.txt");  

        //create a file    
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);    

        //Declaring, creating, and intialize arrays
        String[] instrumentList = new String [10];
        String[] instrumentContent = new String [10];
        int[] stringNumber = new int [10];

        //input string names into array
        instrumentList[0] = "Guitar";
        instrumentList[1] = "Violin";
        instrumentList[2] = "Bass Guitar";
        instrumentList[3] = "Cello";
        instrumentList[4] = "Banjo";
        instrumentList[5] = "Sitar";
        instrumentList[6] = "Rabab";
        instrumentList[7] = "Viola";
        instrumentList[8] = "Harp";
        instrumentList[9] = "Ukulele";
        //input string amounts into array
        stringNumber[0] = 5;
        stringNumber[1] = 4;
        stringNumber[2] = 5;
        stringNumber[3] = 4;
        stringNumber[4] = 5;
        stringNumber[5] = 18;
        stringNumber[6] = 3;
        stringNumber[7] = 4;
        stringNumber[8] = 47;
        stringNumber[9] = 4;

        for (int i = 0; i < instrumentContent.length; i++){//begin for loop
            StringInstrument instrumentList[i] = new StringInstrument();
            output.println(instrumentList[i].InstrumentNameDisplay());
            output.println(instrumentList[i].NumberOfStrings(stringNumber[i]));
            output.println(instrumentList[i].TuneInstrument());
            output.println(instrumentList[i].PlayInstrument());    
            output.println(instrumentList[i].PlayInstrumentBand());
            output.println(instrumentList[i].StopPlayInstrument());
       }//end for loop
      }//end main 
 }//end class
```

Comment: We don't need anywhere near this much info.  What we do need, is just about the only thing you didn't provide, the exact error you're getting and what line it's occurring at exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared `instrumentList[]` as an array of `Strings`.  Your `for` loop attempts calling the following method on these `Strings`:

1. `InstrumentNameDisplay()`
2. `NumberOfStrings(String)`
3. `TuneInstrument()`
4. `PlayInstrument()
5. `PlayInstrumentBand()`
6. `StopPlayInstrument()`

None of these are methods of the `String` class.

It looks like what you might be trying to do is build an array of `Instruments`...